# SQL Join 2 tables with different columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a single login function for usernames and password that exist across 2 tables.
Currently I have

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE username = usernameIN AND password = passwordIN
SELECT * FROM STAFF WHERE username = usernameIN AND password = passwordIN
```

If there is a match ill log the user in.

Is there a query to join these 2 tables so I can run 1 SQL query on them.

Input tables

```
CUSTOMER
username,password,firstname,lastname,addressline1,town

andys,pass123,andy,smith,123 fake st,fake town

STAFF
username,password,firstname,lastname,position,salary

davidq,pass321,david,queen,manager,10000
```

Expected Output from SQL Query

```
OUTPUT TABLE   
username,password,firstname,lastname,addressline1,town,position,salary

andys,pass123,andy,smith,123 fake st,fake town,null,null
davidq,pass321,david,queen,null,null,manager,10000
```

Comment: Use a `UNION` of the two tables

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Do a `UNION ALL`. Select `null` for "missing" columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT username,
       password1,
       firstname,
       lastname,
       addressline1,
       town,
       NULL AS manager,
       NULL AS salary
FROM customer
UNION ALL
SELECT username,
       password1,
       firstname,
       lastname,
       NULL,
       NULL,
       POSITION,
       salary
FROM staff;
```

You can add `WHERE` clauses to your individual queries accordingly.

More over if you want to avoid duplicate rows, use `UNION`

**Result:**

```
username    password1   firstname   lastname    addressline1    town            manager     salary
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
andys       pass123     andy        smith       123 fake st     fake town       NULL        NULL
davidq      pass321     david       queen       NULL            NULL            manager     10000
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b09d1/4)**

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  username,password,firstname,lastname,addressline1,town, null as position, null as salary
FROM
  CUSTOMER  
WHERE username = usernameIN AND password = passwordIN  
UNION ALL  
SELECT  
  username,password,firstname,lastname, null, null, position,salary  
FROM  
  STAFF  
WHERE username = usernameIN AND password = passwordIN
```

You'll have to add aliases

Answer (score 1):

You can join both the table using UNION like below.

```
SELECT username, password, firstname, lastname, addressline1, town, position, salary FROM 
(SELECT username, password, firstname, lastname, addressline1, town, null position, null salary FROM CUSTOMER
UNION ALL
SELECT username, password, firstname, lastname, null addressline1, null town, position,salary FROM STAFF) AS t
WHERE t.username = 'username' AND t.password = 'password'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```